# How remove render blocking css from wordpress when you build a theme?

Tags: theme-development, css, wp-enqueue-style

Is there any good way to avoid render blocking css (google page speed) from Wordpress. Probably more complex, but find a way to add in theme development. It means, not something very specific but global.

I already try to move css files into the footer, nothing change.

I know there is a way by loading css with js to make them asynchron. Basically it creates the link tag only when it reach the inline script.  But is this a correct way to add this in a theme (it means not doing any register_style etc)? Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

[Autoptimize](https://wordpress.org/plugins/autoptimize/) is a kind of solution. Alternative solution is [W3 Total Cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/)

Comment: Is there a way to do it without plugin?